# How do I remove trailing elements in a Scala collection?

Tags: scala

Let's say I have a list that looks something like this:

```
List(0,5,34,0,9,0,0,0)
```

What I'd like to end up with is:

```
List(0,5,34,0,9)
```

I'm removing all the trailing zero's. Is there a method, something like:

```
list.trimRight(_ == 0)
```

that will accomplish that? I could write it from scratch, but it seems to me that it's something that'd come with the std collections?

I came up with:

```
list.take(list.lastIndexWhere(_ != 0) + 1)
```

Is there a better approach?

Comment: There is `dropWhile`, but that would require a few reverses as well...

Comment: I think your solution is the most efficient one.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to know which is the most *elegant*, then I would say

```
list.reverse.dropWhile(_ == 0).reverse
```

since it only needs to refer to the input once, and the intent is very clear.

If you want to know which is the most *efficient*, you need to do some benchmarking.  The results (for your short test list) might surprise you!

```
// Slowest
191 ns     dhg's EnhancedSeq
173 ns     user unknown's custom dropRight
 91 ns     andyczerwonka's take/lastIndexWhere
 85 ns     Rex's :\ (foldRight) -- see below
 60 ns     dhg / Daniel's reverse/dropWhile/reverse
 52 ns     Rex's customDropTrailingZeros -- see below
// Fastest
```

There may be some modest machine-to-machine differences, but basically this is a case where for short lists being fancy does not help you.  Things may change considerably with very long lists.

Here's the fold version (but the stack overflows on large lists):

```
(list :\ list.take(0)){ (x,ys) => if (x==0 && ys.isEmpty) ys else x :: ys }
```

Here's the custom version (completely non-generic--good only for this specific task!):

```
@annotation.tailrec def customDropZeros(
  xs: List[Int],
  buffer: Array[Int] = new Array[Int](16),
  n: Int = 0
): List[Int] = {
  if (xs.isEmpty) {
    var ys = xs
    var m = n
    while (m>0 && buffer(m-1)==0) m -= 1
    var i = m-1
    while (i>=0) {
      ys = buffer(i) :: ys
      i -= 1
    }
    ys
  }
  else {
    val b2 = (
      if (n<buffer.length) buffer
      else java.util.Arrays.copyOf(buffer, buffer.length*2)
    )
    b2(n) = xs.head
    customDropZeros(xs.tail, b2, n+1)
  }
}
```

#### tl;dr

Use `reverse dropWhile reverse` unless you have good reason to otherwise.  It's surprisingly fast and surprisingly clear.

Comment: If I remove the dynamic predicate passing, and use static "!=0" instead, I gain a speed up from roughly 9 to 1. Sacrificing the tailrec call, and sorting on the fly is another speed improvement, as well as using Int intstead of T, but all three are not that impressive. However, dhgS enhancedSeq uses a generic Type and a predicate, variable at runtime, too.

Comment: Wow, I would have thought my approach was faster than Daniel's reverse.dropWhile... Although I think my approach was just as clear.

Comment: @andyczerwonka: I made my own benchmark, and for a List of 4M values, most of them 0 `(for (x <- 1 to n) yield random.nextInt (1000) / 998).toList` the trend of time spent by the algos didn't stabilize, the Graph is oscillating much down from 3.6M to 4M values, 9 to 5s, 5 to 2s - interestingly over all algorithms I tested, maybe a caching phenomenon or the JIT is just stepping in. My own solution is always worse. Yours is at the top. I didn't test dhgs code, because it didn't fit to the common interface.

Comment: @userunknown - That's probably collection.  GC can take a long time when you have 4-8M new objects suddenly floating around.  Anyway, for really long sequences, you really _don't_ want to use `List`; `Vector` is the way to go when you need to do things like drop the end.

Comment: @userunknown, oh, i see what happened!  Your definition of `enhanceSeq` doesn't actually define it.  The definition needs to contain `= new EnhancedSeq(seq)`.  Somehow you missed that when copying/pasting. Then you can just do `i.dropRightWhile(_ == 0)`.  I added a comment to your gist file showing the correction.

Comment: so you're saying on a larger dataset that my solution seems to be the fastest, interesting.. wonder what the triggers are versus the reverse approach

Comment: @dhg: Yes, the `=new EnhancedSeq (seq)` slipped away, when my mighty cut-n-paste-mouse tried to catch your code. :) I updated the code, rerun the benchmark and updated gist and graph.

Comment: @andyczerwonka - It's less the length of the list and more the fraction of items removed that matters.  On my machine, if 5 of 8 items are trimmed, reverse still wins, but if 6 of 8 are trimmed, take wins.

Answer (score 6):

I guess my answer of `list.take(list.lastIndexWhere(_ != 0)+1)` is the way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

```
scala> val xs = List(0,5,34,0,9,0,0,0)
xs: List[Int] = List(0, 5, 34, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0)

scala> xs.reverse.dropWhile(_ == 0).reverse
res1: List[Int] = List(0, 5, 34, 0, 9)
```

**EDIT:**

Here's a one-pass (O(n)) way that adds an implicit `dropWhileRight` method to `Seq`

```
class EnhancedSeq[A, Repr <: Seq[A]](seq: SeqLike[A, Repr]) {
  def dropRightWhile[That](p: A => Boolean)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, A, That]): That = {
    val b = bf(seq.asInstanceOf[Repr])

    val buffer = collection.mutable.Buffer[A]()
    for (x <- seq) {
      buffer += x
      if (!p(x)) {
        b ++= buffer
        buffer.clear()
      }
    }

    b.result
  }
}
implicit def enhanceSeq[A, Repr <: Seq[A]](seq: SeqLike[A, Repr]) = new EnhancedSeq(seq)
```

And you just use it like this:

```
scala> List(0,5,34,0,9,0,0,0).dropRightWhile(_ == 0)
res2: List[Int] = List(0, 5, 34, 0, 9)
```

Comment: Is that more efficient than my solution? `list.take(list.lastIndexWhere(_ != 0))`

Comment: nice, although I'm not sure the overhead of maintaining that class is worth the effort.

Answer (score 3):

There's no such method in Scala, and `List` is highly inefficient when changing it's "end". Prefer `Vector`.

This works reasonably well with `List` (my other suggestion was full of errors, and I deleted it):

```
list.reverse.dropWhile(_ == 0).reverse
```

Comment: I think `seq.last` be preferable to `seq(seq.length - 1)`.  `Vector` defines `last` as `apply(length-1)`, so it's no less efficient.

Comment: @dhg You're probably right. There are other problems as well. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You may traverse the list, and buffer the 0s until you find some non-0. If you find a not-0, you append the buffer to the result so far, and go ahead. But if your List ends with a 0, you throw the last buffer away.

But - in the end, a `reverse` is still needed.

```
val xs = List(0,5,34,0,9,0,0,0)

import annotation._
@tailrec    
def dropRight [T] (l: List[T], p: (T=>Boolean), carry: List[T]=List.empty, buf: List[T]=List.empty): List[T] = {
  if (l.isEmpty) carry.reverse else 
  if (p (l.head)) dropRight (l.tail, p, l.head :: buf ::: carry, List.empty) else 
  dropRight (l.tail, p, carry, l.head :: buf) }

dropRight (xs, (x: Int) => x != 0) 
res122: List[Int] = List(0, 5, 34, 0, 9)
```

It might be interesting if you aren't interested in the order in the end, and could omit the 'reverse' call but why would you then only drop the last Ts?

Benchmark:
[image: benchmark diagram]

- [Source for the benchmark](https://gist.github.com/2773229)
- [Needed parent for benchmark](https://gist.github.com/1152783)

I increased the size further, but the pattern repeated.

#### updated: Included dhg's algorithm, which is pretty performant.